# Writing data into CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a code that is basically doing this:

```
row1 = []
count = 0
writer = csv.writer(myFile)
row = []
for j in range(0, 2):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        row1.append(i+count)
    count = count + 1
    print(row1)
    writer.writerows(row1)
    row1[:] = []
```

I'm creating some lists and I want to map each value to a column, like this

[image]

This error showed it up `iterable expected`. How can I do that?

Comment: `writerows` (plural) expects nested lists (or tuples), each sublist representing a single row. Can't test but it looks like you just need to call the singular `writerow` method

Comment: OMG, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

@roganjosh is right, what you need to write one row at a time is `writerow`:

```
import csv

myFile = open("aaa.csv", "w", newline="")

row1 = []
count = 0
writer = csv.writer(myFile)
row = []
for j in range(0, 2):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        row1.append(i+count)
    count = count + 1
    print(row1)
    writer.writerow(row1)
    row1[:] = []

myFile.close() # Don't forget to close your file
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call the method `.writerow()` instead of the plural `.writerows()`, because you write a single line to the file on each call.

The other method is to write multiple lines at once to the file.

---

Or you could also restructure your code like this to write all the lines at the end:

```
import csv

row_list = []
for j in range(2):
    row = [j+i for i in range(4)]
    row_list.append(row)
# row_list = [
#     [j+i for i in range(4)]
#     for j in range(2)]

with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(row_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler and easier to manipulate tabular data in `pandas` -- is there a reason you don't want to use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(4):
    df[i] = range(i, i+4)

# Any other data wrangling

df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: I disagree. There is no benefit to using pandas here. It won't be any faster and requires a heavy dependency instead of something already readily available in the standard library.

Comment: You're right, I profiled the two different approaches and the `csv` approach is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Any potential pandas speed-up is crippled by the enclosing `for` loop. Plus you have to use string formatting in your loop. Also, you end up with string values while the OP gets ints

Comment: Great point, but I'm not sure how I would get rid of the for loop. Editing out the string formatting now...

Comment: Can't test but at a guess: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)); 
 df.to_csv(index=False)` and the index column is the outer `for` loop. If that doesn't win then it's pandas IO working against you. Either way, we're getting off topic from the question. Bottom line of my point: don't instinctively go to pandas when you see the letters CSV :)