# Exporting lists to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

In Python, I'm trying to export data as CSV for custom music tuning programs.

---

This is my goal (column1 goes from 0-127, column2 is a list of musical pitches expressed as frequencies).
[The Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYFmF.png)

I just need to remove this first row.
[Where I'm at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHrR4.png)

---

The conversation in this thread helped me lots.
[Writing data into CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088987/writing-data-into-csv-file)

In playing with code from that thread, I reached my goal in Python Visualizer, but only for a portion of the code.

[Visualizer Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmRoa.png)

All my code:

```
# Ask user for the Home Frequency

print('What is your home frequency?')
raw_tonic = input()
t = int(raw_tonic)


# Ask user for an EDO

print('how many notes per octave do you want?')
raw_edo = input()
e = int(raw_edo)

# Spit out these frequencies into CSV



import csv

myFile = open("edotest9.csv", "w", newline="")

row = []
count = 0
writer = csv.writer(myFile)
row1 = []
for n in range(1, 129):
    for i in range(1, 2):
        row1.append(((t*2**((n-69)/e))))
    count = count + 1
    print(row1)
    writer.writerow(row1)
    row1[:] = [n]


myFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general procedure for writing a CSV in python goes like this:

> 1. Construct a 2D array. Each array in this 2D array represents your row in a CSV.
> 2. Create CSV file by feeding this 2D array to the **writerows** method like I did below.

Code:

```
import csv

# Ask user for the Home Frequency
t = int(input('What is your home frequency?: '))

# Ask user for an EDO
e = int(input('how many notes per octave do you want?: '))

# Split out these frequencies into CSV
rows = []
column2_diff_pattern = [3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
diff_pattern_length = len(column2_diff_pattern)
column2 = 0
pattern_index = 0
for n in range(1, 129):
    row = [n, t*2**((column2-69)/e)]
    rows.append(row)
    column2 = column2 + column2_diff_pattern[pattern_index]
    pattern_index = (pattern_index + 1) % diff_pattern_length
    
# Do 'rows = rows[1:]' for removing the first row

with open('edotest9.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: This worked quite well! How could I control column 1? Your code made it so that both columns 1 and 2 spit out the same numbers. But I would like to have column 1 go from 1-128, one number per row. (Visual example in my original post, title "My Goal")

Comment: Perfect, thanks! 
Do you know how I could select a pattern for 'n' for row 2? For instance, one cycle through the pattern would be n = 69, 72, 75, 77, 80, 83, 86, 88. So a pattern of "3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2".  For column 2, I want to extend that pattern through the entire 1-128 rows, but for column 1, I want to keep it reading 1-128.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    for i in range(1, 2):
        row1.append(((t*2**((n-69)/e))))
```

This line is adding the first row to your csv output. I'd assume that if you removed it then you'll have the goal output.

Comment: Hmm, I see. My problem is that I need the (t*22((n-69)/e)) formula to create the data that will appear on the CSV output file.